Подменить скрипт
Есть сайт example.com. Нужно подменить его скрипт /script.js для меня: когда сайт загружает скрипт, он получает мою версию.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides?hl=ru

Если нужно локально заменить какой-то файл, то можно воспользоваться расширением Resource Override ссылка для Google Chrome.
Имеет возможность загрузки файлов, встроенный редактор, а также имеет возможность подмены HTTP заголовков
